# Trying to D3.nest only part of my csv data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this csv text file, and I am trying to make an array, so that the array has an object for each name (d.name) and the values of the array are the # of people, and Date.

Here is my data for example,

> Series    Name Date   People SMS12000003000000001 Joe  1990-01-01 200
>   SMS12000003000000001  Don  1990-02-01 252 SMS12000003000000001    John
>   1990-03-01    336 SMS12000003000000001    Bob  1990-04-01 112

And all I want is my new d3 nested array to look like

Object
     Key: Name
and then the values be date and people.

Currently my code is,

```
var newarray= 
    d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.Name;})
        .entries(data);

console.log(newarray);
```

I also tried map, using a function(d) and returning d.people and d.date

Answer (score 0):

can you give an example of the output you want?

if it is something like `[{"key" : "John", "values" : 2, etc...}]`, this will work:

```
var data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .rollup(function(v) { return v.length; })
  .entries(data);
```

Comment: Doesnt the rollup function sum the values? I just want for each object , the key be the name of the person, and then the value the date, so if there are 10 dates for the person Bob, for the object that has key Bob, it contain an array of 10 values which are the 10 dates

Comment: @Rich what's wrong with your current code? That should work. What kind of output is it producing instead?

Answer (score -1):

Given how old this question is I imagine you've solved it by now. However, I will answer it for the current version of D3 (version 5):

```js
var data = [];
     d3.csv("mydata.csv", function(d) {
       data.push({
         name: d.Name,
         people: +d.People,
         date: d.Date
       });
     }).then(function(d) {
       var newarray = d3.nest()
                      .key(function(k)  { return k.name; })
                      .entries(data);
      console.log(newarray);
    });
```

D3v5 reads data asynchronously using ES6 promises, so `d3.csv` creates a promise and reads in the data. We build up the data array dropping the series column. When promise of `d3.csv` is fulfilled (reading is complete), the `then` executes the anonymous function holding the nesting code.

Note: `date: d.Date` will leave it as a string, call `new Date(d.Date)` to create a date object, like so: `date: new Date(d.Date)`